# Indexing a PIL image

Tags: python-3.4, python-imaging-library

Is PIL's image coordinate indexing reversed? Is it indexed as image[column, row]?

I have an image which I open using PIL (pillow)

```
img = Image.open('picture.png').load()
```

and when I try to print the pixel value of the first row, second column

```
print(img[0,1])
```

I get the pixel value of the 2nd row's first column

Can anyone clear this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PIL [indexes images in Cartesian co-ordinates](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/handbook/concepts.html#coordinate-system). So it is indexed as `img[col, row]`.

Comment: I believe array indexing is still technically Cartesian. Cartesian coordinates are not restricted to the (horizontal, vertical) convention. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Two_dimensions).